# SQL Combine two queries and SUM

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok I am a little rusty in SQL. I have 2 exactly same tables with columns ID, Name, Gender, BG. BG is a internal reference. I can query each table individually:

```
SELECT Gender,BG, COUNT(BG) CountValue
FROM income 
GROUP BY Gender,BG
```

Result:

```
   F AA 63 
   F BA 55
   M BB 3
```

and

```
SELECT Gender, BG, COUNT(BG) CountValue
FROM outcome
GROUP BY Gender, BG
```

Result:

```
   F AA 12 
   F BA 4
   M BB 54
```

I try to aggregated both using `UNION ALL` what resulted with a combination of the results bellow. I want to sum them together with the result:

```
F AA 75 
F BA 59
M BB 57
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having two identical tables is usually a problem with the data model.  You should have one table with another column to indicate "income" or "outcome".

But, you can use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select gender, bg, sum(cnt)
from ((select gender, bg, count(*) as cnt
       from income
       group by gender, bg
      ) union all
      (select gender, bg, count(*) as cnt
       from outcome
       group by gender, bg
      ) 
     ) io
group by gender, bg;
```

Using `union all` ensures that groups that are in only one table are in the result set.  Doing the `group by` first allows each subquery to be optimized, say if there is an index.  However, there is overhead for the outer `group by` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it is an internal requirement to have these w tables but the select statement worked amazing. Thanks.